# Qual è il significato di "lettura incrociata" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Su Liber Liber ho trovato questo interessante [testo di Umberto Eco](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/e/eco/de_bibliotheca/html/testo.htm). In modo ironico, Eco descrive un modello negativo di biblioteca, cioè elenca le caratteristiche che dovrebbe avere una biblioteca cattiva. Una è questa:

> I libri consegnati dall'inserviente perché richiesti su scheda non possono essere portati in sala consultazione, cioè bisogna dividere la propria vita in due aspetti fondamentali, uno per la lettura e l'altro per la consultazione, cioè la biblioteca deve scoraggiare la **lettura incrociata** di più libri perché provoca strabismo.

Non riesco a capire il significato di "lettura incrociata" in questo passaggio, nonostante abbia letto le diverse accezioni dell'aggettivo "incrociato" in alcuni dizionari. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Suppongo intenda “avere due o più libri aperti davanti e confrontarli o cercare su uno i riferimenti fatti in un altro.”

Comment: Aggiungo che, trattandosi di un ipotetico modello di cattiva biblioteca, ne consegue che la pratica della "lettura incrociata" in realtà è da favorire. Ciò non può tuttavia verificarsi nelle biblioteche in cui sala lettura e sala consultazione sono due ambienti distinti, perché impedisce una contestuale verifica dei riferimenti ad altri libri contenuti nel libro stesso (quella che Eco chiama "lettura incrociata"), resi possibili dalla consultazione libera a scaffale.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con entrambi i commenti di egreg e Alessio. Per "lettura incrociata" si intende proprio la consultazione contemporanea di due o più testi per cercare raffronti o riferimenti. Probabilmente oggi potremmo parlare di "ipertesto".

Answer (score -1):

Fare una lettura incrociata di due testi significa metterli a confronto in maniera critica. Umberto Eco sta descrivendo un'ipotetica biblioteca in cui si vuol inibire la libera ricerca tarpando le ali al pensiero critico con la scusa di preservare la salute dell'avventore. 
Un po' come quando in Arabia Saudita hanno vietato alle donne di guidare le automobili perché secondo i legislatori potevano ricevere danno alle ovaie ed al bacino mettendo quindi a repentaglio la loro fertilità!

Comment: Hai qualche fonte?

Comment: La definizione di lettura incrociata ti è stata correttamente data nei commenti alla tua domanda sopra. La vena ironica del racconto di Eco non saprei proprio come dimostrartela :)